# Volumes by integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help on this question:
Find the volume of the solid formed when the region bounded by the curves $y = x^3 + 1, x = 1$ and $y = 0$ is rotated about the $x$-axis.

I did $$V = \pi \int_{-1}^0 (x^3+1)^2 dx = \frac{23\pi}{14},$$ but that was wrong. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Check your limits of integration. One of them is incorrect. Other than that, you should be OK. Also, check your algebra and/or your arithmetic. For the integral you did, even with the limits you used, it doesn't come out to $\frac{23\pi}{14}$.

Comment: Camryn, welcome to Math.SE! I hope you stick around to contribute to the site.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try integrating $$V = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (x^3+1)^2 dx$$

(You're given $x=1$ which will be your upper limit of the integral.)

You can see the region enclosed by the curve and the two given lines x=1 (vertical) and $y=0$ (the x-axis.)

[image]

Comment: You're Welcome, camryn.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You have the right idea, except that $y = x^3 + 1$ is not an even function.  Hence, the integral over $[-1,0]$ isn't the same as over $[0,1]$.